# UWP Disable Left-Right-Swipe by Pivot

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a Pivot with four PivotItems. In the second PivotItem, is the Content an UserControl. 
In this UserControl I placed a Button.
I want to disable the Left-Right Swipe-Event If I press the button...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MSDN docs : https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.pivot.aspx

IsLocked
Read/write
Gets or sets whether the Pivot is locked to show only the current PivotItem. While the Pivot is locked, all other PivotItems are removed, and the user cannot navigate to them.

Comment: Thx! it can be so easy :D ^^